# vsto (word office addin) : save read-only document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

How can I save read-only document without save dialog. I have tried to change status of file by using FileInfo IsReadOnly property before ActiveDocument.Save() ,but it didn't help. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Word opens the document **as** Read-Only (check out the title bar). Changing the FileInfo of the opened file won't change that.

Comment: So how can I save active document without save dialog ?

Answer (score 1):

Use SaveAs() rather than Save(). If you have changed the file to read-write before saving then you can provide the current file's name to overwrite it.

Comment: Ok I resolved problem by changing File IsReadOnly property and then reopening document, but i am still wondering if there is easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some of this:

- http://www.office-forums.com/word-savecopyas-t1864812.html
- http://www.darinhiggins.com/implementing-document-savecopyas-in-word/

Unfortunately there is no build-in SaveCopyAs-Method in Word.

Regards, Jörg